# Variable selection using genetic algorithm and partial least squares in R

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to develop a method for variable selection using genetic algorithm and partial least squares in R. For this purpose I am using the package `GA` and the package `plsdepot`. However there seems to be some error in my code which I am unable to identify.I am using the `GA` package for the first time and very new to the ideas of genetic algorithm and partial least squares regression. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
library(plsdepot)
library(GA)


mod <- plsreg1(Data[, 3:137], Data[, 2, drop = FALSE], comps = 100,crosval=TRUE)

x <- Data[,3:137]
y <- Data[,2]


fitness <- function(string) {
  inc <- which(string == 1)
  X <- cbind(1, x[,inc])
  model <- plsreg1(y, X, comps =2,crosval=TRUE)
  q2list<-model$Q2[3]
  best_comp<-which(q2list==max(q2list))
  model_final<-plsreg1(y, X, comps =best_comp,crosval=TRUE)
  q2list_final<-model_final$Q2[3]
  max(q2list_final)
}

GA <- ga("binary", fitness = fitness, nBits = ncol(x),names = colnames(x), monitor = plot)
```

When the code is run i am getting the following error in console

```
> GA <- ga("binary", fitness = fitness, nBits = ncol(x),names = colnames(x), monitor = plot)
Error in plsreg1(y, X, comps = 2, crosval = TRUE) : 
predictors must contain more than one column
Called from: fitness(Pop[i, ], ...)
Browse[1]> Q
```

on checking if x is empty or not

```
> ncol(x)
[1] 135
```

In terms of errors I think the main problem seems to be the X matrix is staying blank as its somehow unable to read the x matrix.
When I am running the GA code source viewer is opening up and this is what its showing

```
function (predictors, response, comps = 2, crosval = TRUE) 
{
    X = as.matrix(predictors)
    n = nrow(X)
    p = ncol(X)
    if (p < 2) 
        stop("\npredictors must contain more than one column")     'This is where the error is happening as p is < 2'
    if (is.null(colnames(X))) 
        colnames(X) = paste(rep("X", p), 1:p, sep = "")
    if (is.null(rownames(X))) 
        rownames(X) = 1:n
    Y = as.matrix(response)
    if (ncol(Y) != 1) 
        stop("\nresponse must be a single variable")
    if (any(is.na(response))) 
        stop("\nresponse must not contain missing values")
    if (nrow(X) != nrow(Y)) 
        stop("\npredictors and response have different number of rows")
    if (is.null(colnames(Y))) 
        colnames(Y) = "Y"
    if (is.null(rownames(Y))) 
        rownames(Y) = 1:n
    if (any(is.na(X))) 
        na.miss = TRUE
    else na.miss = FALSE
    if (!is.null(comps)) {
        nc = comps
        if (mode(nc) != "numeric" || length(nc) != 1 || nc <= 
            1 || (nc%%1) != 0 || nc > min(n, p)) 
            nc = min(n, p)
        if (nc == n) 
            nc = n - 1
    }
    else {
        if (na.miss) {
            crosval = FALSE
            nc = 2
        }
        else {
            if (n >= 10) 
                crosval = TRUE
            else crosval = FALSE
            nc = min(n, p)
        }
    }
    if (!is.logical(crosval)) 
        crosval = FALSE
    Xx = scale(X)
    Yy = scale(Y)
    X.old = Xx
    Y.old = Yy
    Th = matrix(NA, n, nc)
    Ph = matrix(NA, p, nc)
    Wh = matrix(NA, p, nc)
    Uh = matrix(NA, n, nc)
    ch = rep(NA, nc)
    Hot = matrix(NA, n, nc)
    hlim = rep(NA, nc)
    if (crosval) {
        RSS = c(n - 1, rep(NA, nc))
        PRESS = rep(NA, nc)
        Q2 = rep(NA, nc)
        sets_size = c(rep(n%/%10, 9), n - 9 * (n%/%10))
        obs = sample(1:n, size = n)
        segments = vector("list", length = 10)
        ini = cumsum(sets_size) - sets_size + 1
        fin = cumsum(sets_size)
        for (k in 1:10) segments[[k]] = obs[ini[k]:fin[k]]
    }
    w.old = rep(1, p)
    t.new = rep(1, n)
    p.new = rep(NA, p)
    h = 1
    repeat {
        if (na.miss) {
            for (j in 1:p) {
                i.exist = which(complete.cases(X[, j]))
                w.old[j] = sum(X.old[i.exist, j] * Y.old[i.exist])
            }
            w.new = w.old/sqrt(sum(w.old^2))
            for (i in 1:n) {
                j.exist = which(complete.cases(X[i, ]))
                t.new[i] = sum(X.old[i, j.exist] * w.new[j.exist])
            }
            for (j in 1:p) {
                i.exist = intersect(which(complete.cases(X[, 
                  j])), which(complete.cases(t.new)))
                p.new[j] = sum(X.old[i.exist, j] * t.new[i.exist])/sum(t.new[i.exist]^2)
            }
            c.new = t(Y.old) %*% t.new/sum(t.new^2)
            u.new = Y.old/as.vector(c.new)
        }
        if (!na.miss) {
            w.old = t(X.old) %*% Y.old/sum(Y.old^2)
            w.new = w.old/sqrt(sum(w.old^2))
            t.new = X.old %*% w.new
            p.new = t(X.old) %*% t.new/sum(t.new^2)
            c.new = t(Y.old) %*% t.new/sum(t.new^2)
            u.new = Y.old/as.vector(c.new)
            if (crosval) {
                RSS[h + 1] = sum((Y.old - t.new %*% c.new)^2)
                press = rep(0, 10)
                for (i in 1:10) {
                  aux = segments[[i]]
                  Xy.aux = t(X.old[-aux, ]) %*% Y.old[-aux]
                  wh.si = Xy.aux %*% sqrt(solve(t(Xy.aux) %*% 
                    Xy.aux))
                  th.si = X.old[-aux, ] %*% wh.si
                  ch.si = t(Y.old[-aux]) %*% th.si %*% solve(t(th.si) %*% 
                    th.si)
                  ch.si = as.vector(ch.si)
                  Yhat.si = ch.si * X.old[aux, ] %*% wh.si
                  press[i] = sum((Y.old[aux] - Yhat.si)^2)
                }
                PRESS[h] = sum(press)
                Q2[h] = 1 - PRESS[h]/RSS[h]
            }
        }
        Y.old = Y.old - (t.new %*% c.new)
        X.old = X.old - (t.new %*% t(p.new))
        Th[, h] = t.new
        Ph[, h] = p.new
        Wh[, h] = w.new
        Uh[, h] = u.new
        ch[h] = c.new
        Hot[, h] = (n/(n - 1)) * t.new^2/(sum(t.new^2)/(n - 1))
        hlim[h] = qf(0.95, h, n - h) * (h * (n^2 - 1))/(n * (n - 
            h))
        if (is.null(comps) && crosval) {
            if (Q2[h] < 0.0975 || h == nc) 
                break
        }
        else {
            if (h == nc) 
                break
        }
        h = h + 1
    }
    if (crosval) {
        q2cum = rep(NA, h)
        for (k in 1:h) q2cum[k] = prod(PRESS[1:k])/prod(RSS[1:k])
        Q2cum = 1 - q2cum
        Q2cv = cbind(PRESS[1:h], RSS[1:h], Q2[1:h], rep(0.0975, 
            h), Q2cum)
        dimnames(Q2cv) = list(1:h, c("PRESS", "RSS", "Q2", "LimQ2", 
            "Q2cum"))
        if (is.null(comps)) 
            h = h - 1
    }
    if (!crosval) 
        Q2cv = NULL
    Th = Th[, 1:h]
    Ph = Ph[, 1:h]
    Wh = Wh[, 1:h]
    Uh = Uh[, 1:h]
    ch = ch[1:h]
    Ws = Wh %*% solve(t(Ph) %*% Wh)
    Bs = as.vector(Ws %*% ch)
    if (!na.miss) {
        Br = Bs * (rep(apply(Y, 2, sd), p)/apply(X, 2, sd))
        cte = as.vector(colMeans(Y) - Br %*% apply(X, 2, mean))
        y.hat = as.vector(X %*% Br + cte)
        cor.xyt = cor(cbind(Xx, y = Yy), Th)
    }
    else {
        mu.x <- attributes(Xx)$"scaled:center"
        sd.x <- attributes(Xx)$"scaled:scale"
        X.hat = Th %*% t(Ph) %*% diag(sd.x, p, p) + matrix(rep(mu.x, 
            each = n), n, p)
        Br = Bs * (rep(apply(Y, 2, sd), p)/sd.x)
        cte = as.vector(colMeans(response) - Br %*% mu.x)
        y.hat = as.vector(X.hat %*% Br + cte)
        cor.xyt = matrix(NA, p + 1, h)
        for (j in 1:p) {
            i.exist <- which(complete.cases(X[, j]))
            cor.xyt[j, ] = cor(Xx[i.exist, j], Th[i.exist, ])
        }
        cor.xyt[p + 1, ] = cor(Yy, Th)
    }
    resid = as.vector(Y - y.hat)
    R2 = as.vector(cor(Th, Yy))^2
    R2Xy = t(apply(cor.xyt^2, 1, cumsum))
    T2hot = rbind(hlim[1:h], t(apply(Hot[, 1:h], 1, cumsum)))
    dimnames(Wh) = list(colnames(X), paste(rep("w", h), 1:h, 
        sep = ""))
    dimnames(Ws) = list(colnames(X), paste(rep("w*", h), 1:h, 
        sep = ""))
    dimnames(Th) = list(rownames(X), paste(rep("t", h), 1:h, 
        sep = ""))
    dimnames(Ph) = list(colnames(X), paste(rep("p", h), 1:h, 
        sep = ""))
    dimnames(Uh) = list(rownames(Y), paste(rep("u", h), 1:h, 
        sep = ""))
    names(ch) = paste(rep("c", h), 1:h, sep = "")
    dimnames(T2hot) = list(c("T2", rownames(X)), paste(rep("H", 
        h), 1:h, sep = ""))
    names(Bs) = colnames(X)
    names(Br) = colnames(X)
    names(resid) = rownames(Y)
    names(y.hat) = rownames(Y)
    names(R2) = paste(rep("t", h), 1:h, sep = "")
    colnames(R2Xy) = paste(rep("t", h), 1:h, sep = "")
    dimnames(cor.xyt) = list(c(colnames(X), colnames(Y)), colnames(Th))
    res = list(x.scores = Th, x.loads = Ph, y.scores = Uh, y.loads = ch, 
        cor.xyt = cor.xyt, raw.wgs = Wh, mod.wgs = Ws, std.coefs = Bs, 
        reg.coefs = c(Intercept = cte, Br), R2 = R2, R2Xy = R2Xy, 
        y.pred = y.hat, resid = resid, T2 = T2hot, Q2 = Q2cv, 
        y = response)
    class(res) = "plsreg1"
    return(res)
}
```

Comment: "some error" is just *way* too vague. Please provide details.

Comment: Sorry for the vague query. I have modified my answer

Comment: @AaghazHussain When you edit posts, please don't use inline code formatting for highlighting technical words. It's *code* formatting, so it's meant for code.

Comment: X is empty would seem to indicate that x were not loaded properly in "x <- Data[,3:137]".  Can you see if that were the case (i.e. x is empty?)

Comment: @javadba I have edited my question answering your query

Comment: This Matlab code could help you : http://www.models.life.ku.dk/GAPLS.